# как из webview получить сообщения из js

Tags: android

как из  webview получить сообщения  из js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте JavaScriptInterface для webview.

Пример кода:

```
public class JavascriptInterfaceActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;

    JavaScriptInterface JSInterface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "JSInterface"); 

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html");

    }


    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void changeActivity()
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(JavascriptInterfaceActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function displaymessage()
        {
             JSInterface.changeActivity();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```